# Regex find and replace all words

Tags: regex, replace

Reg-ex always confuses me, plus super simple syntax's are hard to Google. I am using reg-ex here strictly with find and replace no need for any languages to do some reg-ex just want to save time editing a lot of data :)

I have a huge json file, these are only two pieces of data, but it's good for this example.

```
[
    {
       name: 'John',
       team: 'Wolves',
       team_id: 1,
       number: 24
    },
    {
       name: 'Kevin',
       team: 'Rockets',
       team_id: 1,
       number: 6
    }
]
```

Inside my json I need to put double quotes over pretty much every key:value pair, numbers are optional.

I need to get rid of the single quotes, then put double quotes over everything.

**Final result looking like this.**

```
[
    {
       "name": "John",
       "team": "Wolves",
       "team_id": "1",
       "number": "24"
    },
    {
       "name": "Kevin",
       "team": "Rockets",
       "team_id": "1",
       "number": "6"
    }
]
```

Again, numbers are optional but it would be nice to know how to double quote those.

Extra: I vaguely remember doing something like this awhile back, but can't find where I found that information. This would be a nice reference. Does anyone have any good links to the basics of regex, I just want to save time when working with a lot of data. Thanks.

Comment: You should tag the language for more exposure and so users know which language you are using.

Comment: I tagged find-and-replace, it actually changed it for me to replace, but what are language are you referring to the json, or the javascript I am using? Those don't really matter do they? Most text editors come with find and replace on them with a reg-ex option that allows easier code editing. That is where I will be using the reg-ex

Comment: Using sublime text if that matters? I just want some simple find syntax, and then some simple replace with syntax. I have used simple syntax before, but it's so simple its hard to find lol.

Comment: javascript is a good tag for exposure, if that's what you're using.

Comment: for ALL of your regex needs: http://www.visibone.com/regular-expressions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something along the lines of this:

`(\w+):\s*('?)([^']+?)\2(?=[\n,])` and replace by `"\1": "\3"`

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/pX9xX6

Edit:
Just tested in Sublime, seems to work fine.

Comment: Thanks this looks a little more clear I think, still looks confusing, let me try this as well, thanks for the demo!!

Comment: I really like that link it explains the regex... This is cool 1+ maybe I can learn a little but here.

Comment: Bookmarked the site, bet it will come in handy. It worked great in the site, I couldn't get it to work in sublime, probably something I was doing. I just pasted in my json to that site and it worked nicely.

Comment: I'm glad it worked out. If you want to learn more, use the debugger to see how the regex is working: http://regex101.com/r/rJ5qL5/#debugger -- I got it to work in sublime btw.

Comment: Thanks I kind of do, regex looks confusing but I bet its not so bad, its quite useful, so thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the exact syntax depends on the tool. If you were using `vim`, for instance:

```
:%s/'\([^']*\)'/"\1"/g
```

and

```
:%s/^\([ ^I]*\)\([^ ^I]*\):/\1"\2":/
```

would probably do the trick, although you'd want to do a manual check for any quoted quotes..

Comment: Cool thanks, regex is powerful but it looks so confusing, I think there is a face in that code that is smiling. Let me try it, bet it works.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work, probably didn't give enough specifications. Ill keep trying though 1+ because I bet this works, just doing something goofy on my end.